# SQL query to perform operations between rows and columns grouping the results by name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql database that contains a table for storing data from executed tasks. The table contains the dates corresponding to the status of the task (initializing, ready, executed). I need to perform operations that allow me to obtain results on these dates, the problem is that the operations are between different rows and columns.

Here is a sample of my data table. Dates are values in Unix TimeStamp (bigint).
As the time is in Unix (integer), the table below I put only an illustrative number (they can be used in the same way for the solution)

```
    +----------+-----+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
    | taskName |  Id |    State     |  Date1  |  Date2  |  Date3  |
    +----------+-----+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
    |   T10    |  1  | initializing |     1   |   2     |     3   |
    |   T10    |  1  |    ready     |     4   |   5     |     6   |  
    |   T10    |  1  |   executed   |     7   |   8     |     9   |
    |   T20    |  2  | initializing |     10  |   11    |     12  |
    |   T20    |  2  |    ready     |     13  |   14    |     15  | 
    |   T20    |  2  |   executed   |     16  |   17    |     18  |
    |   T10    |  3  | initializing |     72  |   74    |     76  |
    |   T10    |  3  |    ready     |     78  |   80    |     82  |  
    |   T10    |  3  |   executed   |     84  |   86    |     88  |
    |   T30    |  4  | initializing |     28  |   29    |     30  |
    |   T30    |  4  |    ready     |     31  |   32    |     33  | 
    |   T30    |  4  |   executed   |     34  |   35    |     36  |

                                     ... 
    +----------+-----+--------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

- in column Date1 (dt1 = time the state was reached)
- in column Date2 (dt2 = time the state was loaded)
- in column Date3 (dt3 = time the state was completed)

I need to perform operations between task dates with the same id and after grouping the results by the task name. The operations are (Considering a task with the same id):

- dt2 (state = ready) - dt1 (state = initializing)      > oepration1
- dt3 (state = executed) - dt2 (state = ready)          > operation2
- dt3 (state = executed) - dt1 (state = initializing)   > operation3

For each task, corresponding to the same id, these operations must be performed and after the results they must be grouped (perform the average of the results) in the tasks that contain the same name.

for the rows in the example table, the result should be:

```
    +----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | taskName |  avg_operation1 |  avg_operation2 |  avg_operation3  |
    +----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
    |    T10   |         6       |         6       |         12       |
    |    T20   |         4       |         4       |          8       |
    |    T30   |         4       |         4       |          8       |
    +----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

I can't think of a way to do this, with the knowledge I have. If anyone can give me some way to go.

Comment: Hi Jhonata. Why are there three date columns? What do they signify? i.e. if something is executed - why are there three dates associated with one execution?

Comment: These are dates that correspond to actions that were performed in the task. But to solve the case they are not important, as they are in bigint numeric format. The results of operations between the two numbers (which correspond to the date) can be positive or negative
I put it in a generic format, but for each state (line) there are different values.

Comment: OK. Indulge me for a second please. So what is the difference in meaning between the (in line 1)  {task 10, id 1, initializing, dt1} and {task 10, id 1, initializing, dt2}?

Comment: in line 1: dt1, dt2, dt3 are different values: (
dt1 = time the state was reached
dt2 = time the state was loaded
dt3 = time the state was completed). 

[[dt1, dt2 and dt3 of line 1, is different from the values ​​of dt1, dt2, dt3 of line 2, and so on.]]

Comment: OK, I think it would be helpful to edit the headers to indicate this. Will give it a go. Thanks for the extra context!

Comment: OK thank you. I will put this information in the question.

Comment: You should probably replace these `dtX` with actual date values, both in the sample data and desired results. This way, we can better understand the computation you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - also not sure if the `datediff` makes a difference depending on the date format
With the following in mind:

```
Date1 = State_Reached  
Date2 = State_Loaded  
Date3 = State_Completed
```

Query

```
SELECT ID, Agg_Table.Task, AVG(Agg_Table.Op_1) as Avg_Op1, AVG(Agg_Table.Op_2) as Avg_Op2, AVG(Agg_Table.Op_3) as Avg_Op3
FROM
 (SELECT
   Task,
   DATEDIFF(IF(State='Ready', State_Loaded, NULL), IF(State='Initialized', State_Reached, NULL)) as Op_1,
   DATEDIFF(IF(State='Executed', State_Completed, NULL), IF(State='Ready', State_Loaded, NULL)) as Op_2,
   DATEDIFF(IF(State='Executed', State_Completed, NULL), IF(State='Initialized', State_Reached, NULL)) as Op_3
  FROM Table_Name 
 ) as Agg_Table
GROUP BY ID, Agg_Table.Task
```

Also for the future, might help to normalize this table. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Play with this:

```
select s1.taskName, avg(s1.op1), avg(s1.op2), avg(s1.op3) from
  (select taskName, if(state = 'ready', dt2-d1, NULL) as op1, if(state = 'executed', dt3-d2, NULL) as op2, if(state = 'executed', dt3-d1, NULL) as op3
  from funkyfile
  order by taskName, id) as s1
group by s1.taskName;
```

Syntax may be off, quick down and dirty. Did not test.
General suggestion use subquery to get data ready, then process.